# the size of a struct containing bitfields

Tags: c, pointers, bit-fields, strict-aliasing

I have a `struct` as follows.

```
struct A {
  uint32_t a : 1;
  uint32_t b : 1;
};
```

Is `struct A` guaranteed by the standard to have size 4? Is it possible that a compiler instead
uses only one byte for `struct A` since it uses exactly two bits?

```
struct B {
  uint32_t a : 1;
  uint32_t b : 1;
  uint32_t c : 30;
} b;
```

If I would like to set the bitfields in `b` to zero, since `sizeof(struct B) = 4`, it looks good to me to do so by
`*(uint32_t*)&b = 0`. But I saw a lot of discussions on SO arguing that such a pointer cast is a bad practice. I wonder what makes `*(uint32_t*)&b = 0` bad here and what I should do (I know I can use `memset` to reset the bitfields but I am interested in other portable ways).

Comment: Note that the true goal here is: "to set the bitfields in b to zero".  The title question of "the size of a struct containing bitfields" is really not the issue.  To find the implementation's size of `struct B` is simply `sizeof(struct B)`, but that is not a relevant issue to the best way to "to set the bitfields in b to zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `struct A` guaranteed by the standard to have size 4?

No.  It might be size 4, might not.

> Is it possible that a compiler instead uses only one byte for struct A since it uses exactly two bits?

Yes, it is *possible*.

> I wonder what makes `*(uint32_t*)&b = 0` bad here ...

- Assignment may be insufficient to zero out `b`.
- Rare: the optional type `uint32_t` may not exist.
- Code risks aliasing issues.

> ... and what I should do

To zero out `b`, assign a `struct B` that is zero.  Research *compound literal*.  Notice this code below applies to various types, not just `struct` with *bit-fields*.

```
b = (struct B){0};
```

Or maybe, if you desire a non-zero value:

```
b = (struct B){.a = 0, .c = 42, .b = 1};
```

---

*Bit fields* are tricky.  Use `signed int`, `unsigned int` and `_Bool` and not `uint32_t` for maximum portability.

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether
> atomic types are permitted. C17dr § 6.7.2.1 5

Comment: If I understand correctly, `struct B` and `uint32_t` have the same alignment. Therefore, "may fail due to different pointer alignment needs" seems not an issue here. Moreover, could you please give more details about "Code may assign out `b` (UB). Assignment may be insufficient to zero out `b`"?

Comment: @user18676624 Yes, the alignment concern I had was trying the cast to `struct B*`.  Alignment issue removed. As `struct B` may have a different size than `uint32_t` (more or less), then `*(uint32_t*)&b = 0 ` writes too much or maybe not enough.

Comment: @user18676624 Detail "struct B and uint32_t have the same alignment." is incorrect, but the alignment needs of `uin32_t` will not exceed the alignment needs of `struct B`.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious how `struct B` can have size smaller than `uint32_t` since the bitfields in total costs 32 bits. Also, since all bitfields can be packed into a 4-byte storage unit, doesn't `struct B` have size exactly 4? Or, is it because the compiler may use a storage unit that is smaller than 4 bytes?

Comment: @user18676624  `struct B` cannot have size smaller than `uint32_t`.  I was thinking of `struct A`. Answer updated.  For `struct B`, the compiler may use a storage unit that is larger than 32-bit.  Packing is not required.  If you want a 32-bit object, use `uint32_t`.  That optional type very commonly exists.

Comment: I see. According to your answer, `struct B` already uses `uint32_t` and thus uses 4-byte storage unit. So, is it `sizeof(struct B) = 4`?

Comment: No, it is `sizeof(struct B) >= sizeof(unit32_t)`.  `>=`, not `=`.  As it is 4 in your implementation, that is an implementation detail, not required by C.

Answer (score 2):

The first question, you can add an alignment, but this will affect the execution efficiency:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct A {
    uint32_t a : 1;
    uint32_t b : 1;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The second question, you can define it as union

```
union B {
    struct {
        uint32_t a : 1;
        uint32_t b : 1;
        uint32_t c : 30;
    };
    uint32_t u;
} b;

// set the bitfields in b to zero
b.u = 0;
```